# Launch daemon in MacOs only once on boot

Tags: macos, daemon, startup, launchd

I cant make daemon launches only one time on startup.

I created file /Library/LaunchDaemons/local.gz.startup.plist
Then I run loaded it with launchd command

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding=="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
   “http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
       <plist version="1.0">
        <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>local.gz.startup</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
        <string>/etc/rc.local</string>
        </array>
        <key>RunAtLoad</key>
        <true/>
        </dict>
       </plist>
```

rc.local:

```
#!/bin/bash    
sudo mkdir /Volumes/ESP
sudo mount -t msdos /dev/disk0s1 /Volumes/ESP/
....
sudo umount -f /Volumes/ESP/
exit
```

This works only when I load it manually with launchd command, not at startup.
I have tried another parameters, but it (rc.local) begins work continuously, it mounts and unmounts /dev/disk0s1.

How can I make it start only once on boot?

Comment: Try adding `<key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key><true/>` to the .plist. Also, you shouldn't need `sudo` in the script, since it's already running as root; on the other hand, you probably *should* have error checking & handling in the script.